# What is the best alternative of Quantlib library

Tags: fixed-income, programming, quant-trading-strategies, risk-management, quantlib

We need to build a Fixed Income Portfolio Risk Analytics solution. Somehow due to administrative reason we can't use Quantlib which is written in C++, even call it through SWIG via JNI.

We have tried Jquantlib, but it seems not 100% replica of original Quantlib which is written in C++ have bugs( for e.g. root not bracketed error in bond yield calculation).

So right now we can see two options [opengamma](http://strata.opengamma.io/)
and [Maygard](https://github.com/odeyemis/maygard) (the google [archive](http://code.google.com/p/maygard/)) which is written in Pure Java.

Can any experienced users share their views on this two library or if they know any better pure Java-based libary alternative.

Comment: FINCAD has the F3 product, which is very flexible, and has built-in adjoint algorithmic differentiation, for very fast risk calcs.  It is implemented internally in C++, but they have supported bindings for Java, .NET, MATLAB, and maybe Python.  Disclosure: I work for FINCAD.

Comment: But FINCAD is not open-source.

Answer (score 10):

The Strata project is the new pure Java market risk quant library from OpenGamma. For more information, see the [documentation](http://strata.opengamma.io/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/OpenGamma/Strata). It is Apache v2 licensed.

Strata takes the experience of the OG-Platform codebase referenced in the question and turns it into a library - no need for databases, servers or similar. Ease of use is a big focus and there are examples to allow easy evaluation. See this link for [asset class coverage](http://strata.opengamma.io/product_coverage/).

Disclaimer: I work for OpenGamma, who develop Strata.

Comment: Hi JodaStephen, welcome to Quant.SE!

Comment: I was curious, so I checked out the source code.  I'm not a fan of Java for numerical analysis or computational finance but the options pricers and some numerical routines look pretty decent.  A few quibbles at the lower level (like unnecessary matrix inverses).  Overall Strata looks like a pretty good library, particularly for risk.  It seems better in several ways than QuantLib.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! If there is anything that you saw that want us to try and fix, feel free to raise an issue at GitHub or on our forum.

Answer (score 6):

I did not tested it by now, but Google released a library similar to quantlib **written in TensorFlow** ([tf-quant-finance](https://github.com/google/tf-quant-finance)). It may be worthwhile to test it (and to post here your views on it), because once you are in TF, you can

- easily **distribute your computations over a grid** of computers (including GCP or AWS)
- if you are a machine **learning enthousiastic**: use it to backprop a [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) over any parameter
- and you should probably be able to use TF **automatic differentiation** features (see [Mini-symposium on automatic differentiation and its applications in the financial industry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02311))

Comment: Do you have a link to this library?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne added in the answer

Answer (score 4):

QSTK is nice and open source , it is the QuantSciTookKit and it has some good functionality if you are interested in python programming. Here is the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/QuantSoftware/QuantSoftwareToolkit).

Comment: QSTK is terribly outdated.